# Grouping by shifted DATETIME field and PIVOT by ID

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'm having table with schema (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE [Test]
(
  CaptureTime DATETIME,
  SnapShotValue INT,
  Id INT
);
```

With following 30 minute data:

[image: 30 minute data]

And I want calculate average value for every HH:00 hour data take values HH:30 and HH+1:00 values and PIVOT them. For test data above:

[image: Dest data view]

I'm starting [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1311875/1614367/group-by-datetime-field) and how to group values HH:00 hour data take values HH:30 and HH+1:00 values and Pivot? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can offset the capture time by 30 minutes, then remove the minutes, and finally do conditional aggregation:

```
select dateadd(minute, - datepart(minute, v.capturetime), v.capturetime) capture_time,
    avg(case when id = 1 then 1.0 * snapshotvalue end) avg1,
    avg(case when id = 2 then 1.0 * snapshotvalue end) avg2
from test t
cross apply (values (dateadd(minute, - 30, capturetime))) v(capturetime)
group by dateadd(minute, - datepart(minute, v.capturetime), v.capturetime)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a357f050beb18b9cbb1a7d6acd5ff124)**

Comment: Incorrect syntax near v: cross apply (values (datepart(minute, capturetime)) v(captureminute)

Comment: @amaranth: my bad, there was a missing closing parenthesis. Fixed.

Comment: I got following:
capturetime avg1 avg2
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 112 120
2012-01-01 01:00:00.000 123 123
2012-01-01 02:00:00.000 126 NULL
I think there is incorrect range time for my condition

Comment: In first, the column names is not ID - 1 or 2 in example. In second, for calc avg for ID 1 in time 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 get values from 2012-01-01 00:30:00.000 is 111 and 2012-01-01 01:00:00.000 is 115 - avg will be (111+115)/2=113

Comment: Now avg calc is right. But the ID numbers may be different and I can't write every ID in SELECT. In second How to get column names by their IDs ?

Comment: Probably, I think, grouping must be by Id, and in SELECT change CASE conditions to using different count and Values of Id column. I.e IDs may be next 2, 3, 4, 5, ... 200.

Comment: @amaranth: *How to get column names by their IDs*: that is not possible in pure SQL. A SQL query must return a *fixed*, predefined set of columns. WHata you ask for requires dynamic SQL, which is much more complicated. You might want to search for "dynamic pivot" on Google and/or Stack Overflow.